# How to override the props of a component?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm unable to override the props of the MediaPlaceholder component. As a test I simply try to set the disableMediaButtons property to true but it's value doesn't change and there is no error message.

Here is the code I tried:

```
const MyMediaPlaceholder = createHigherOrderComponent( (MediaPlaceholder) => {
    return (props) => {
        props.disableMediaButtons = true;
        console.log(props);
        return wp.element.createElement(
            MediaPlaceholder,
            props,
        );
    };
}, 'MyMediaPlaceholder' );

addFilter(
    'editor.MediaPlaceholder',
    'my/MediaPlaceholder',
    MyMediaPlaceholder
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to override the props so I am sharing it. The props can't be overwritten directly so I used **Object.assign()** to do it.

The following line:

```
props.disableMediaButtons = true;
```

Should be instead:

```
props = Object.assign({}, props, { disableMediaButtons: true });
```